# Tizen studio failed to build Stopwatch template

Tags: tizen

I got this error in console after building Stopwatch template:

```
13:07:32 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Stopwatch ****
ninja all 
[1/5] Building res/edje/main.edj
[2/5] Building src/data.o
[3/5] Building src/view.o
[4/5] Building src/main.o
FAILED: edje_cc -deps .d -id "../edje/images" -id "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/images" -sd "../edje/sounds" -sd "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/sounds" -fd "../edje/fonts" -fd "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/fonts" ../res/edje/main.edc res/edje/main.edj
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: fatal: ReadFile: Referensen (handle) is wrong.
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

'edje_cc' is a kind of compiler for edc file.
You can check how to use edje_cc below.

> edje_cc [OPTIONS] input_file.edc [output_file.edj]

I checked your log :

> edje_cc -deps .d -id "../edje/images" -id "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/images" -sd "../edje/sounds" -sd "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/sounds" -fd "../edje/fonts" -fd "E:/Tizen/tools/edc-editor/share/enventor/fonts" ../res/edje/main.edc res/edje/main.edj

input_file.edc and outpur_file.edj are looking at different paths(imo, output path is wrong). Have you ever changed the path of edc?

If possible, please re-create the stopwatch sample app.

BRs, Jin.